# How to avoid a lot of conditional programming in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, code-cleanup

Let's imagine that we have this code:

There is a lot of standard data-checking (if property exists... for..if has own...end etc.)  So does it a "normal code"? Because my Java friend saw it and he asked me: Why did you write low-quality code?

And other question: Is there some way exists to simplify data-checking in every method etc? For ex: "check if property in obj exists".  (I didn't want to use typescript). I worked with it a lot but I want to know how it can be done by the plain JS.  (I tried to use es7 decorators but they are only working with methods. Not the pure function etc.)

```
var resultList;
var obj = {

    elem1 : [
    {
        "type" : "zeta_0"
    },
    {
        "type" : "beta_0"
    },
    {
        "type" : "omega_0"
    }
  ],

    elem2 : [
    {
        "type" : "zeta_1"
    },
    {
        "type" : "beta_1"
    },
    {
        "type" : "omega_1"
    }
  ]

}

function fillResultSet(sourceData) {

    var res = [];

    if (sourceData && sourceData.elem1) {

    for (var key in sourceData) {

      if (sourceData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        res.push(sourceData[key][0].type);
      }

    }

  }

  return res;

}

resultList = fillResultSet(obj);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4jrcadse/)

Comment: the point here is your algorithm, there's no dirty code if you know the syntax and what you're doing. Please tell your friend about that.

Comment: You want to stoe all the types in an array?

Comment: IMO, there's nothing wrong with using `.hasOwnProperty()`, you should tell your friend about that. Javascript is NOT Java

Comment: Thank you friends! Actually I have a lot of expirience with JS but I want to know, maybe I do something wrong and something can be better. But looks like in that case it's normal, because I thought a lot about that and didn't have any idea, so that's why I asked you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return an array of all the types using functional programming use this:

```
function fillResultSet(sourceData) {
    var result = [];
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sourceData || {}).forEach(function(key){
        sourceData[key].forEach(function(e){
            result.push(e.type);
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thak you for your help, but I want to ask you (it's just a question). Does the side-effects is a normal behavior of the functional programming? I know that in F programming we should avoid any side-effects and a function should be pure

Comment: @Velidan side effects occur when a function changes a variable that is outside its scope. Here `fillResultSet` is totally pure as it's doesn't change any outside variable. But the anonimous functions (callbacks) passed to both `forEach` are not pure since they change the value of `result` which is outside both of their scopes. But that isn't a problem since all of this is wrapped inside `fillResultSet` which is the main function here and it has no side effects.

Comment: Awesome! You bring me the light. Seriously, I was always thinking that the functional programming should avoid any (any in general) side-effects and I never understand...how it's possible. Now it's a little bit clear for me. Thank you so much Ibrahim!

Comment: @Velidan Just note that if those callbacks change a variable that is outside `fillResultSet` itself, then `fillResultSet` won't be pure as its execution caused an external variable to be changed. So to conclude **A FUNCTION IS PURE ONLY IF ITS EXECUTION DIDN'T CAUSE AN OUTSIDE VARIABLE TO BE CHANGED, OTHERWISE, IT'S NOT PURE AND IT HAS SIDE EFFECTS**.

Comment: @Velidan Here is a good article about it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). It mentions the depending factor too (as pure functions should not depend on outside variables neither).

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at map (Why do you need identifiers in the main object, cant it be an array ?):

```
result=Object.values(obj).map(el=>el[0].type);
```

As "doesnt exist" is falsy in js, the easiest pattern to have an if if sth exists is the OR  (||) operator:

```
(document.getElementById("test")||document.body).innerHTML="test";
```

Comment: Not, it is a response from the backend so I can't change it :)

Comment: @Velidan no problem Array.from(object)

Comment: Thank you so much Jonas for your help!

Comment: @velidan: youre welcome ;) by the way, i dont get the good thing about the acepted answer. Your for/if will run much faster and is much safer. just sayin